# Getting CommandBean or form bean object with out @ModelAttribute in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement of getting commandbean or form bean object into the controller without using `@ModelAttribute` either from ModelMap or HttpServletRequest or anything else.

My code is:

JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="user" method="POST"
           action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/createUser">
        Name:<form:input path="name" />
        Password:<form:input path="password" />   

       <input type="submit"/>

    </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(ModelMap model) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "userRegistration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user=(User)model.get("user");// Retruns null
    //Tried using request object but user object is not available in it. 
    return "message";
}
}
```

I tried different ways but nothing worked out.

Comment: Why is it that you cannot use `@ModelAttribute` because that is the whole point of that annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to create the bean manually, then (for example) use a [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) to declare it. The argument resolvers supportsParameter method should check the expected type of the parameter. After that you can add a parameter in your Controller that is of the desired type.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, I tried this before i had an issue with creation of user bean since i cannot get it from request parameters it has to be generic i.e., it should work for any bean and the request params are not the same for each model. Do you have any idea of how spring actual builds the model Attribute object and how we can access that object.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. You could try to use reflection to match request parameters to bean properties... but that would just be rewriting @ModelAttribute functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it *by hand* like you would do if you did not know the magic of Spring : just the the `HttpServletRequest` and gets its parameters to feed your `User`. It could look like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user= new User();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if (name != null) {
        user.setName(name);
    }
    if (password!= null) {
        user.setPassword(password);
    }
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    //Tried using request object but user object is not available in it. 
    return "message";
}
```

Or in a more terse way : `user.setName(request.getParameter("name");`